# Firebase get wrong data when offline

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have an int in Firebase called ultimaRefloteActual. As can be seen later, it has a value of 1054. However, when the user goes offline for some reason, Firebase assigns it a value of 1 (sometimes). Why?

[image: ultimaRefLoteActual in Firebase]

I think my procedure to get data is not trustable enough. How can I fix it? I tried to use int in the future, then I changed to String in the future, but I have the same error.

```
Future<String> cargarUltimaRefLoteActual( String idEmpresa) async {
  String ultimaRef;
  Query resp = db.child('datos/ultimaRefLoteActual');
  final snapshot = await resp.once();
  if (snapshot.value == null) return '';
  ultimaRef = snapshot.value.toString();
  print(ultimaRef)
  return ultimaRef;
}
```

I would prefer the result to be null if the value didn't have it in the cache, but not wrong data. How can I be sure to retrieve a right data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enabled disk persistence, I suspect the 1 may be coming from the local cache. If that is the case, and you don't want to get to get outdated values, you have two options:

1. Don't use disk persistence.
2. Force the cache to stay up to date, by calling [`keepSynced`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/keepSynced.html) on `db.child('datos/ultimaRefLoteActual')` then the app starts.

Comment: Thanks @puf. I don't know the full path when the app start. Can I use it in any other place, right?

Comment: Sure. It works anywhere. It's more idiomatic to do at startup, because: 1) you need to do it only once per run of the app, 2) you need to redo it every run of the app.